# Finding minimum element in array using STL in C++

Tags: c++, stl

Why the output is coming to be 50 it should have been 20.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int v[] = {10, 20, 30, 50, 20, 70, 30};

  int* i1;
  i1 = std::min_element(v + 3, v + 4);

  cout << *i1 << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

STL algorithms operate on *half-open ranges*, which are usually denoted as `[first, last)`. This means the `first` element is *included* in the range, the `last` element is *not included*. Hence

```
[v + 3, v + 4)
```

specifies a range of length 1, and the only element in that range has the value `50`.The result of `*std::min_element(v + 3, v + 4)` can be nothing but `50`.

Comment: If you want to search the whole array, use `std::min_element(v, v + 7)` instead, or better `std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v))`